# Как указать в regexp символ перевода строки?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Как указать в regexp символ перевода строки и еще несколько символов `#, !, =, :, пробел`.
Как-то так?

```
(" #!=:\n\r")
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`\n` - перевод строки

`\s` - один из символов пробела Unicode и эквивалент `[\t\n\v\f\r \u00a0\u2000\u2001\u2002\u2003\u2004\u2005\u2006\u2007\u2008\u2009\u200a\u200b\u2028\u2029\u3000]` https://stackoverflow.com/a/2429180
`\u0020` - сам символ пробела https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html

`\n\#\!\=\:\s`

В самом выражении спец.символы могут быть записаны так (если не ошибаюсь): `[@#$%^&+=]`

https://htmlweb.ru/java/regexp.php

Пример: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664434/escaping-special-characters-in-java-regular-expressions

Comment: `\s` - не пробел, а любой пробельный символ.

Comment: @Qwertiy
Спасибо! Дополнил ответ...

Comment: `\r` для win систем не учли.

Answer (score 4):

Ну, во первых в джаве два слэша ставится, в данном случае `\\s+` будет обозначать любое количество пробельных символов начиная с 1-го, тут и перевод строки пробелы тоже входят. Конкретно для этой цели : `"#|!|=|:|\\s"`.